# Java RMI Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, rmi

My project gets class Cast Exception when I started server and then I tried to add customer using add customer UI but when I tried for it it returns a Class Cast Exception from the server connector class.

interface CustomerController

```
    public interface CustomerController {
    public boolean addCustomer(Customer customer)throws RemoteException,IOException,ClassNotFoundException;
}
```

ServerStart,java

```
    public class ServerStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
            Registry registry=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(5050);
            System.out.println("Server is starting..");
            registry.rebind("Server", new CustomerControllerImpl());
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerStart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

ServerConnector.java

```
    public class ServerConnector {

    private static ServerConnector serverConnector;
    private CustomerController customerController;

    private ServerConnector() throws NotBoundException, MalformedURLException, RemoteException {
        customerController = (CustomerController) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:5050/Server");
    }

    public static ServerConnector getServerConnector() throws NotBoundException, MalformedURLException, RemoteException {
        if (serverConnector == null) {
            serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
        }
        return serverConnector;
    }

    public CustomerController getCustomerController() {
        return customerController;
    }
}
```

Class cast Exception occurs at ServerConnector.java file at

```
customerController = (CustomerController) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:5050/Server");
```

CustomerControllerImpl.java

```
    public class CustomerControllerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CustomerController{

    private final CustomerFileAccess customerFileAccess = new CustomerFileAccess();

    public CustomerControllerImpl() throws RemoteException{

    }

    @Override
    public boolean addCustomer(Customer customer) throws RemoteException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return customerFileAccess.addCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

here I attached the [netbeans project which can be download thourgh this link](http://www.filedropper.com/errornbprojects)

Thank you!.

Comment: Post any code related to the question here not on an external site

Comment: Could you please add the code where the actual ClassCastException happens? And am I right to assume the exception happens on the client side?

Comment: @LarsGendner customerController = (CustomerController) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:5050/Server");

Comment: First question:  Are you sure CustomerControllerImpl has been declared as implementing CustomerController?   (Incidentally, a ClassCastException will normally have a message saying something along the lines of "X cannot be cast to Y" which can often help diagnose the issue.)

Comment: @daiscog yes I have implemented CustomerController for class CustomerControllerImpl I have also added that code part at the end of the question

Comment: @tryor - so what is the type of the object being returned?  Try doing a `System.out.println(Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:5050/Server").getClass().getName());` to find out.

Comment: @daiscog it returns Proxy[Remote,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.1.2:56022](remote),objID:[3d305374:14fad52e661:-7fff, 642629386611017081]]]]]

Comment: Where is the exception? Stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html#define%60), I *believe* it may be because your interface does not extend java.rmi.Remote.

Comment: No worries. If you're ever in Cardiff, buy me a beer ;-)